How to get sum of all values for keys in a cosmos db
I have a cosmos db with documents that look like this:
{
"id": "dfc0634b-ed98-47e6-ae7c-498294938e9e",
"data": {
    "1110_ClassA_20241014": 500,
    "1111_ClassA_20241224": 600,
    "1112_ClassB_20241014": 500
}

}
I want to get sum of all the values for keys in data field where the key contains ClassA and 20241224. So, the output would be 600.
I could figure out a sql query that can do what I want?
Any suggestions or guidance? Otherwise, I will resort to using dotnet api.
Thanks.

The way you have modelled this is wrong. Instead of having keys named after data values you should have an array of objects. So as a first iteration "data": [{"Key" : "1110_ClassA_20241014", "Value": 500},{"Key" : "1111_ClassA_20241224", "Value": 600},{"Key" : "1112_ClassB_20241014", "Value": 500}] though next the "Key" property should actually be replaced by 3 different properties so you don't have to do substring searches to find ones matching "ClassA_20241014" and can just use equality operations on these properties (that can use an index)

Having property names containing data is an anti pattern that makes the queries against the transactional store less efficient and more unwieldy and is highly problematic if you ever desire to use the analytical store feature as you quickly will exceed the maximum number of distinct property paths that the inferred analytical store schema will support

Can you provide any query that you have tried so far? and your expected output?

There are two anti-patterns here: 1) using values as keys; and 2) an Unbounded Array (where any amount of data can be combined either in the data {} sub-element or (if you refactor) a data [] array - this can lead to the eventual situation of document-size exceeding what's possible.

Aside from all that: you haven't shown any work. Please edit to provide a [mcve] with your efforts (not just sample data; expected vs actual behavior, code/query, errors, etc)
